# Can Spring Boot load new letsencrypt certificates without shutting down?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, jetty, undertow

Can Spring Boot load new letsencrypt certificates without shutting down?  I imagine that this may depend on which server it is embedding (Undertow, tomcat, jetty, etc.)?